# Getting error "Object variable or With Block variable not set" while finding column number

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find column number of cell where text "Remarks" is present in row 1. In my case row 1 and row 2 are merged.
I am using below logic to find the column number, but I am getting `Runtime error 91; Object variable or With Block variable not set`

```
Dim lnRow As Long, lnCol As Long

lnRow = 1
lnCol = Sheet1.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Remarks", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're assuming the `Find` is successful.

Comment: Yes.. I assume it will always be successful. And I am getting this error even when find was successful

Comment: Do you have a sheet with the code name of `Sheet1`?

Answer (score 2):

Chaining `.Column` on the end here will fail when the `Find` is unsuccessful:

Test if the `Find` succeeded in the following manner, and then return the `.Column`.

```
Dim remarksRng as Range
Set remarksRng = Sheet1.Rows(lnRow).Find(What:="Remarks", _
                      LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Not remarksRng Is Nothing Then
    lnCol = remarksRng.Col
Else
    ' not found; handle here
End If
```